# Impressão com recursividade em formato de triângulo

Tags: c, loop, recursão

Tenho que ler um valor inteiro e passá-lo como parâmetro para uma função. Esta deve mostrar o número usando o formato exemplificado.

Ex: se o número informado foi 3, mostrar:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
```

Consigo mostrar o formato que pede a questão, mas não os como exatamente pede.

Conseguir fazer isso.

ps: o caractere `@` é apenas para testar.

```
void triangulo(int n){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 1 ;i <= n; i++){
        for(j = 1 ;j <= i ; j++){
            printf("@");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
     int n;
     scanf("%d", &n);

     triangulo(n);   
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: o enunciado está confuso...qual a relação de 3 com 1 1 2 1 2 3 ? isso não está claro...

Comment: na verdade, a edição saiu errada.

Comment: mas conseguir resolver

Comment: a saída é pra ficar assim 1 "\n" 1 2 "\n" 1 2 3 "\n"

Comment: @DenilsonSilva Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Faltou só colocar o número no lugar do "@":

```
#include <stdio.h>

void triangulo(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) printf("%d ", j);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
     int n;
     scanf("%d", &n);
     triangulo(n);   
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ff9fYA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wyamrjtu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/PrintNumber.c).

Só houve uma confusão de conceitos, ou você faz recursivo ou faz iterativo e o que você fez foi, acertadamente, iterativo, não é um problema ideal para recursividade, embora possa ser usada, e claramente vê-se que ela é mais complicada, especialmente se fizer duplamente recursivo.

Comment: assim que fiz a pergunta, vi que tava errando besteira, mas valeu mesmo assim Maniero

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente não colocaria uma resposta completa, mas esse é um exercício interessante por causa da recursividade.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void rectri(int n)
{
  int i;

  if (n == 0)
    return;

  rectri(n-1);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d ", i+1);

  printf("\n");

}

int main()
{
  rectri(5);
}
```

Teste no terminal:

```
[zv@localhost so]$ ./so339810
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5 
[zv@localhost so]$
```